# Что я не так делаю(angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular-routing, angular-ui-router, frontend

Коллеги здравствуйте.

У меня есть много компонентов, я использую router и во время пере-направления routera я столкнулся с проблемой, опишу подробно:

У меня есть один заглавной файл app.component.html он отображает целиком все компоненты, то бишь полностью сайт, но теперь я сделал с помощью routera компонент about, при клике на него отобразить всё, что я записал в about.component.html, тут-то и возникает проблема, когда я кликаю на about, сам about отображается, но вместе с ним отображается и сайт тоже, то бишь заглавная страница + about а надо чтобы при клике отображалось только то что я записал в about.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё так запутанно. Может код или структуру добавите?

Comment: <navbar></navbar>
<jumbotrone></jumbotrone>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
Вот у меня есть такой код в app.component.html и он отображает всё правильно но когда я с помощью роутера подлючаю about и скажем у меня в about есть всего одна строчка <h1>Hello World</h1> при клике на about отображается мой hello world и сама структура app.component.html, надо чтобы при клике на about отображался только hello world без структуры.

Comment: а роутер? можете к вопросу добавить роутер и компонеты которые вызываете?

Comment: Добавил, ещё что то добавить?

Comment: для about должна быть вообще другая страница?

Comment: Да, это то что я хочу сделать, при клике на about должен открываться about.component.html без кода из app.component.html из первой картинки.

Comment: Если да, тогда Вам надо в app.component оставить только router-outlet, остальное перенести либо в HomeComponent либо сделать гнезование и добавить какой то BaseComponent, который будет содержать вот то код который сейчас в app.component

Comment: А, понятно. Спасибо большое за ответ, думаю это и есть решение вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Структура роутинга

```
{
        path: 'home',
        component: BaseComponent,
        children: [
              { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
        ]
    },

    {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent
    },
```

в app.componet.html оставить только

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

а в base.component.html будет то, что в app было

Comment: Что то у меня не получилось, пожалуйста объясните подробнее где мне создать base.component.html , сделать ещё одну папку и сделать 2 файла base.component.ts и html?

Comment: Да,всё правильно. После того как создали в темплейте пишете код который был у вас в app компонете.

Comment: Какие то ошибки получаете?

Comment: Ничего не получаю, белый экран. Но показано что успешно скампилировалось?

Comment: У вас есть team viewer можете залезть и посмотреть?

Comment: вы путь правильно указали /home/ ?

Comment: Вроде пути правильно указал, если ошибку сделать angular же светит.

Comment: const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: BaseComponent,
        children: [
              { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
        ]
    },

    {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent
    },
];

Comment: Это routing....

Comment: и localhost:4200/home/ пусто - так?

Comment: Да пусто ))))))

Comment: https://github.com/pictaile/angular2-example Добавил небольшой пример для наглядности

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду смотреть и исправлять свой